# How to count number of rows based on enum value?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a database table where one of the columns contain an enum

Entity file:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "error_log_entry")
public class ErrorLogEntryEntity extends AbstractPersistable<UUID> {
    
    @Id
    private UUID id;
    

    @Column(name = "priority")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ErrorLogEntryPriorityType priority;

    
}
```

Enum file

```
public enum ErrorLogEntryPriorityType {
    INFO,
    WARN,
    DANGER
}
```

Now I am trying to write a query that counts the number of rows where the enum is equal to "DANGER"

```
public interface ErrorLogEntryRepository extends JpaRepository<ErrorLogEntryEntity, UUID> {
    List<ErrorLogEntryEntity> findByChangedUserId(UUID userId);

    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select count(*) from error_log_entry where priority = 'DANGER'")
    ErrorLogEntryPriorityType getErrorCount();

}
```

However, this causes the following error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to class project.core.types.ErrorLogEntryPriorityType
```

I am a bit new to spring, but from the documentation, this problem seems to occur because I am casting on an incompatible type. I am not 100% sure.
Any suggestions on how to make this query work?

Comment: `count(*)` returns a number, the number of rows that matched your query - int, long, BigInt, etc. So your method should return some numeric type, yet you return `ErrorLogEntryPriorityType`,

Comment: simply replace `ErrorLogEntryPriorityType getErrorCount();` with `BigInteger  getErrorCount();`

Comment: Yeah, my goal is to get the number of rows that contain the enum "DANGER". I thought I could do this with Count. Eg. if three rows contain this enum, then it should return "3"

Comment: @Maflec, no, count(*) returns a number, so it will return 3, rather than "3", which is a string.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the error is because the return type of the query method you've defined is incorrect. You're not looking to get back an instance of `ErrorLogEntryPriorityType`, you need to get back a numerical value - the count of how may records match the query.

Having said that, there's an even easier, cleaner solution - use Spring Data's  "derived query method" and you don't even need to write the `@Query` yourself. For example, this should work as you intend:

```java
long countByPriority(ErrorLogEntryPriorityType priority);
```

Note there is no `@Query` annotation; Spring Data understands the mapping of your entity and generates the query for you based on the method name and parameter types.

This method is also more flexible; the application can use it to count all records with *any* of the values for `priority`, not just `DANGER`. Generally speaking, it's good to have the low-level repository methods be building blocks, like Lego. The application can then assemble a wide variety of "things" from those basic building blocks, such as a service method that counts how many `DANGER` log records there are.

I suggest you read all the reference docs for Spring Data repositories, starting [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories).